Exsistitne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat et avum et avam, ut Anglicum verbum "grandparent"?
Lingua Latina habet verbum quod significat et matrem et patrem, id est "parens". Sed parentes parentium appellantur... quid? Masculini parentes parentium appellantur avi et feminini appellantur avae, sed exsistitne verbum pro et avo et ava?
SUMMARY: Does Latin have a word which means "grandparent"?

Have you found any precedents for "verbum pro X"? I really don't think that's an idiomatic way of saying "word for X."

Do you want to use Classical Latin only, or do you accept Medieval and "Neo" Latin, too? I don't think there is one in Classical Latin.

To echo @brianpck's comment, it might be a good idea to ask a separate question for a suitable idiom for that purpose. If you're unsure about any other construction you're using, the same applies to them. Looking for phrases to use when composing specific Latin prose often makes for good questions.

Puto utendum patribus patrum et similibus.
Ceterum pater avusque significant et progenitores vetustiores.

A common singular word for grandparent to use instead of the gender specific singular words (for use in paternal or maternal grandparent), avus for grandfather or avia for grandmother, is not attested in Classical Latin. A deliberate distinction is made in the singular form of a grandparent, to the plural form of grandparents.
In respect of a singular form of grandparent (masculine or feminine but not a common term for either) two academic publications  are referenced/summarised related to the Latin words for grandparents, as well as other relations. These are:

"What does Latin tell us about the Romans?" by Carl R. Trahman published in The Classical Journal Vol. 67, No. 3 (Feb - Mar 1972,) pp 240-250 and Latin kinship extensions: An interpretation of the data. This JSTOR article is about Romans and their use of kinship terms, about the Romans using very specific terms to signify and identify the family relationships, as opposed to how they are thought of in English, which has a common term for either male or female grandparent.

"Latin kinship extensions: An interpretation of the data" by Archie C. Bush published in Ethnology, Vol. 10, No. 4, (Oct 1971) pp 409-432. This JSTOR article is about Roman kin terms employed by the jurists. Bush starts the article with a list of Latin names for 110 family relationships, sorted into six grades of consanguinity, and the preview given for p409 list grandparents, avus for grandfather avus and or avia for grandmother. Mentioned in the article what-is-a-word-for-grandparents-of-the-same-child is that the system of grades derives from Roman law; a text attributed to the jurist Julius Paulus listed names of 448 family relationships.


The Roman Law Library gives an overview, an explanation of the creation of laws, and versions of books. Examples of the books in the Justinian Code (Codex, Digesta, Institutiones and Novellae) exampls are available on the internet such as at the internet archive. Roman laws or Corpus Iuris Civilis links to De verborum significatione Book 50.16.0. Scrolling down to 50.16.51 gives one example of many which reference the specific singlular words for masculine grandparent and female grandparent.

Gaius libro 23 ad edictum provinciale Appellatione "parentis" non tantum pater, sed etiam avus et proavus et deinceps omnes superiores continentur: sed et mater et avia et proavia.

The feminine and masculine version of each grandparent, and of each greatgrandparent are also named as parents.
This is also similar to this other stackexchange question and answer concerning terms for grandparents and earlier , where there are very specific terms to identify the family relationships, also as referenced above, which clearly distinguish each distinct family relationship, as opposed to English which uses more generic terminology.
A respected elder or wise ancestor might also be referred to in some cultures or languages as a grandparent. In Roman Latin, pater, appears to take this niche, recorded as at the foundation of Rome (subsequently recorded). In The History of Rome by Velleius Paterculus Romulus has a council to assist him.
In Vellei Paterculi Historia Romana Book I.8.6

Hic centum homines electos appellatosque patres instar habuit consilii publici.  Hanc originem nomen patriciorum habet.

The English translation is by Frederick W. Shipley

As a council to assist him in administering affairs of state he had one hundred chosen men called patres. This is the origin of the name patricians.

For the plural term of grandparents, the Lewis & Short Dictionary defines parens, in addition to meaning parents, for its transferred (metaphorical) meaning, as also meaning grandparents, with all ancestors more remote than the grandparents as majores (maiores). The mutliple references given in Lewis & Short are:-

Seyffert ad Cic. Lael.  Cicero laelius de amicitia    p260 (in Latin and German) for reference to maiores
For an English introduction of Laelius De Amicitia  and translation by Wiliam Falconer  In English in his translated text at line 18  maiores is intrepeted/translated as ancestors. Line 27 inter natos et parentes between children and parents, and line 70 is about natural and adopted parents
Liv 21, 43, 6:   Titus Livius, Ab Urbe Condita Book 21  Section 43    is to do with ancestors, as opposed to grandparents.
Dig. 50 16 15  Digesta Iustiniani  Roman laws or Corpus Iuris Civilis. This is the link definitions of 'parentis' within the Corpus Iuris Civilis De verborum significatione mentioned above.

Roman Latin has other terms related to antiquity, maturity, old such as senex, veter, but aren't directly related to grandparents or a grandparent.
For modern Latin, as opposed to Roman Latin, there is the Popes prayer for grandparents for which there is a Latin version. The page will (likely) display in English and then it's necessary to change the language to Latin to read  avis abl. plural and avorum acc. plural (from the masculine form avus) for grandparents. avus masculine grandfather and avia feminine grandmother following this method would then be the same as grandfathers, which is  avi masculine (or mixed gender) plural.  Yes, this would also be as the dative and one version of the ablative for avis meaning bird, but there is still same match genitive single or plural for grandfather, regardless of having it mean grandfathers.
The organisation which hosts the grandparents prayer is named: "The Catholic Grandparents Association is a global organization of the faithful" is translated into the Latin language on their website as "Consociatio Grandparentum Catholica est fidelium ordinatio globalis".
